# Why do the number of passes change in insertion sort when we change the condition for 'i' in for loop?

Tags: c, insertion-sort

Why is it so that in insertion sort when the cases are (n-1) then also if we write for loop for i=0 then we have to consider n cases but in bubble sort where we have to consider (n-1) cases again then we don't face any such problem? I am not getting this thing please help me in this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printArray(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
}

void insertionSort(int *a, int n)
{
    int key, j;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // for number of passes
    {
        printf("\nPass number %d started.", i);
        key = a[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > key)
        {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 54, 65, 7, 23, 9};
    int len = 6;
    printf("Array before insertion sorting:\n");
    printArray(arr, len);
    insertionSort(arr, len);
    printf("\nArray after insertion sorting:\n");
    printArray(arr, len);
    return 0;
}
```

and when we write for loop for i =1, then it takes (n-1) cases. How can the number of cases change with a change in 'i' in the for loop. Shouldn't it be like for(int i = 0;i<n;i++);???

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printArray(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
}

void insertionSort(int *a, int n)
{
    int key, j;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) // for number of passes
    {
        printf("\nPass number %d started.", i);
        key = a[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > key)
        {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 54, 65, 7, 23, 9};
    int len = 6;
    printf("Array before insertion sorting:\n");
    printArray(arr, len);
    insertionSort(arr, len);
    printf("\nArray after insertion sorting:\n");
    printArray(arr, len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have two elements in the array, you need to move at most one. If you have three elements in the array, you need to move at most two. If you have four, three. etc. Always one fewer than `n`, which is why it's start at `1` instead of  `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I got it guys in insertion sort we don't compare index 0 element with anything and that's the reason we have to start it from i =1 whereas in bubble sort we have to compare every element even the element at index 0.